# What does kubectl store in the cache?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I see a cache directory in the .kube/ directory of my kubectl. I tried to find the purpose of this cache and how kubectl uses it in the kubernetes documentation [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/overview/) but couldn't find any clue.

What does kubectl store in the .kube/cache directory? and how this cache is used in the kubectl operation? What exactly kubectl caches?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By cursory examination, one will observe the `discovery` directory is the `kubectl api-resources` output, per cluster hostname, and the `http` sibling directory contains the response bodies for each of those individual `api-resource` requests. The latter is used for [parsing its `Etag`](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/v1.20.1/staging/src/k8s.io/client-go/discovery/cached/disk/round_tripper.go#L34) in order to know whether the cache is intact or not.

The `api-resources` are a formal description of the verbs, URIs, and request/response bodies tolerated by a given kubernetes cluster, which includes any installed Custom Resource Definitions

The gory details are described by the [godoc for `NewCachedDiscoveryClientForConfig`](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/v1.20.1/staging/src/k8s.io/client-go/discovery/cached/disk/cached_discovery.go#L271) and that `~/.kube/config` directory itself is under user influence via the `--cache-dir` flag to `kubectl`, as shown in the [`genericclioptions config_flags.go`](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/v1.20.1/staging/src/k8s.io/cli-runtime/pkg/genericclioptions/config_flags.go#L55)